# how to use input type date to input dates into a calendar

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I would go about making a birthday calendar where I can insert dates (using JS, HTML and CSS). I already have a full calendar. I just dont know how to use input type date to insert a date into it.
Thanks

Comment: By 'full calendar' do you mean the plugin [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)?

Comment: no sorry. that wasnt very clear of me. I just mean a calendar made with html. yismailov.leercloud.nl/kalender2 i wanna know how i can use <input type="date"> to input dates into the calendar

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener to the input field and write an appropriate event handler that processes your date.

See the code below that logs the selected date on the console.

```js
$("#date").on('change', (event) => {
  const date = $(event.target).val();

  // You can do whatever you want with this date
  console.log(date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="date" />
```